# Как добавить нулевой байт к строке в JavaScript

Tags: node.js, javascript

Мне необходимо добавить нулевой байт к строке в Node.JS, как это можно сделать?!
Имеется flash приложение подключённое к сокетному серверу. Если сервер сам отправляет строку то флешка не видит что пришло сообщение (т.к. отсутсвует 0 байт, говорящий о конце передачи сообщения). Если сделать echo сервер, и послать с флеша сообщение то флешка увидит что пришло сообщение (т.к. флеш сам добавляет 0 байт в конец отправляемой строки). Вот как то так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

может быть,

```
str = str + '\0';
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало =)

Comment: @Dexter, в самом деле в JS символ перевода (обычно перевод строки, newline) это '\\0' а не '\\n' ?

Comment: \0 - пробел.

Comment: Перенос строки - \r\n